# Getting elements from a list that has a prefix

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a few lists:

```
list = ["MacOS-1", "MacOS-2", "Windows-1", "Windows-2"]
maclist = []
windowslist = []
```

How do I get elements from "list" and sort them into "maclist" or "windowslist" according to if they have "MacOS" or "Windows" in front of them?

I was thinking: (I haven't tested this yet)

```
for element in list:
  if "MacOs" in element:
    maclist.append(element)
  elif "Windows" in element:
    windowslist.append(element)
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `[x for x in ["MacOS-1", "MacOS-2", "Windows-1", "Windows-2"] if "Windows" in x]`, but there is an actual `startswith()` too, so `[x for x in ["MacOS-1", "MacOS-2", "Windows-1", "Windows-2"] if x.startswith("Windows")]`

Comment: What you've got should work fine. If the correct list items should only ever start with "MacOS" or "Windows" then you could use the `startswith` string method, e.g., `if element.startwith("MacOS"):`

Comment: You could also make things slightly more compact with list comprehension, e.g., `maclist = [item for item in list if item.startswith("MacOS")]`, and similarly for Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`startswith`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_startswith.asp) function in Python.

```py
for element in list:
  if element.startswith("MacOS"):
    maclist.append(element)
  elif element.startswith("Windows"):
    windowslist.append(element)
```

In your code, you don't only check prefixes, also you check all substrings in any index range.

Or, you can use the below implementation:

```py
macos_list = [item for item in item_list if item.startswith("MacOS")]
windows_list = [item for item in item_list if item.startswith("Windows")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into Radix Trees, it is the most efficient way.
Also lots of solutions online.  Eg if the list is long, and you have to do this over and over, then you can sort the list once and then do a biary search on it in log(N), then look in the neighbourhood of the results.